# Disable navigating site via URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I've been trying to find the answer to this question in the forum. Maybe I'm not phrasing is correctly when searching, but is there a way to disable the use of navigation of a deployed site through inputing controllers and methods in the url.

In other words, only allowing navigation through buttons in the views.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this as some sort of security measure you should go stand in a corner and rethink your security-strategy ;)

If not, you could tag-on a session-id or something to every link and button and then verify that in the controller.

I think you should rephrase the question and include *why* you want to do this, maybe we could help you rethink the whole solution...